# How to return the currently active user/session on a graphical Linux desktop session?

Tags: shell-script, shell, users

My question is how to get the user name on the shell, who is currently using the Linux desktop (on a "normal" desktop system, where you usually only have one active user, i.e. no server system here, but just your usual Laptop etc.).
If you really want to imagine a server system, I would be fine with listing all *active* users.

So take e.g. the case that a script is running as root as a cron job (or similar) and I want to get the/all currently active users on the system.

I know I could use `w` or `who` or `users` to get the currently logged in users. That's fine, but that user are logged in does not mean that they are actually currently **using** the desktop, because in all desktop environments I know, users can switch to another user after they have logged in.
I could also use `last` to get the user who last logged in, but this is also no guarantee  that this user is still the active one.

So how can one do this? It is fine to provide specific solutions for different desktops environments (GNOME, KDE, …), but, of course, a cross-compatible solution is preferred.

Comment: My Linux-based laptop can often have two users logged in on it simultaneously. It's also possible that I'm actually using a vTerminal session outside the GUI (Ctrl+Alt+F1). In your terms, which one's active?

Comment: If, for example, your Linux uses `systemd` and `lightdm` (a setup typical for many modern stock Linuxes), you could examine the output of `systemctl status lightdm` and look for the line `"session opened for user <user name> by <user id>"`.

Comment: what do you mean by *active user*? on linux you can have any number of active users.

Comment: @roaima Personally I only care about the graphical sessions (so no terminal) and I only care about the user, whose session is currently *active*, i.e. using it.
As I said when using the device as a server, of course multiple users could be active, but do not imagine this case. Or, if you want,  list all active users…

My use case would be a simple Laptop/PC Linux installation, where usually only one user can be active…

Comment: @wvxvw Thanks, but this only works with lightdm. gdm e.g. does not show me this information.

Comment: If you have a particular definition for "active", as in your comment above, please [add it to your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/394709/edit) for everyone to see. That's how this site works.

Comment: Out of interest, what are you hoping to do with the knowledge of the active user? Send them a message? If so, rather than trying to identify the correct "active" user why not send it to all currently logged in users.

Comment: @roaima Indeed I want to send a message (via zenity or send-notification). Sending to all users would maybe cause error messages and such, so mhh… rather want to send to the active user.

I've already explained my "definition" in the question. It's in the first sentence/paragraph.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On many current distributions, login sessions (graphical and non-graphical) are managed by `logind`. You can list sessions using

```
loginctl list-sessions
```

and then display each session’s properties using

```
loginctl show-session ${SESSIONID}
```

or

```
loginctl session-status ${SESSIONID}
```

(replacing `${SESSIONID}` as appropriate); the difference between the two variants is that `show-session` is designed to be easily parsed, `session-status` is designed for human consumption. Active sessions are identified by their state; you can query that directly using

```
loginctl show-session -p State ${SESSIONID}
```

which will output

```
State=active
```

for the active session(s). The full `show-session` output will tell you which user is connected, which TTY is being used, whether it’s a remote session, whether it’s a graphical session etc.

Note that `logind` can have multiple active sessions, if the system is configured with multiple seats, or if there are remote sessions.

Putting this all together,

```
for sessionid in $(loginctl list-sessions --no-legend | awk '{ print $1 }')
do loginctl show-session -p Id -p Name -p User -p State -p Type -p Remote $sessionid
done
```

will give all the information you need to determine which sessions are active and who is using them, and

```
for sessionid in $(loginctl list-sessions --no-legend | awk '{ print $1 }')
do loginctl show-session -p Id -p Name -p User -p State -p Type -p Remote $sessionid | sort
done |
awk -F= '/Name/ { name = $2 } /User/ { user = $2 } /State/ { state = $2 } /Type/ { type = $2 } /Remote/ { remote = $2 } /User/ && remote == "no" && state == "active" && (type == "x11" || type == "wayland") { print user, name }'
```

will print the identifiers and logins of all active users with graphical sessions.

The `LockedHint` property now indicates whether a given session is locked, so

```
for sessionid in $(loginctl list-sessions --no-legend | awk '{ print $1 }')
do loginctl show-session -p Id -p Name -p User -p State -p Type -p Remote -p LockedHint $sessionid | sort
done |
awk -F= '/Name/ { name = $2 } /User/ { user = $2 } /State/ { state = $2 } /Type/ { type = $2 } /Remote/ { remote = $2 } /LockedHint/ { locked = $2 } /User/ && remote == "no" && state == "active" && (type == "x11" || type == "wayland") { print user, name, locked == "yes" ? "locked" : "unlocked" }'
```

will also indicate whether the active session is locked or not.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to find out if a graphical session is locked or 'open'. In both cases "State=active" is displayed as it seems.

Comment: @Bachi see `LockedHint`, described in the updated answer.

Comment: `loginctl lock-session 3; sleep 10; loginctl show-session -p LockedHint 3` prints `LockedHint=no`. Do you know whether this hint depends on the desktop environment, or did I simply hit a bug?

Comment: @Vir did session 3 actually lock?

Comment: yes. `loginctl unlock-session 3` also unlocks it again

Comment: @Vir from the looks of things, `loginctl` doesn’t set the hint; the hint only changes in response to d-bus messages from the DE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a bash function like the following

```
function Xowner() {
    for pid in $(ps -houid --ppid $(ps -hoppid $(pgrep X))) ; do
        [ "$pid" = "0" ] && continue
        id -n -u $pid
        break
    done
}
```

The intention with that function is basically to pick "the first" non-root UID of the sibling processes of the Xserver. See `man ps` for details. I suppose, if your use case potentially involves multiple X servers, you'll need a better focus on which of them to start from.

Comment: That returns `gdm` in my case…

Answer (score 0):

On most Unix-like systems (says [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whoami)) the command

```
$ whoami
```

gives you the name of the current user running the command, e.g.

```
$ whoami
dessert

$ sudo whoami
root
```

Comment: _"I know I could use `w` or `who` or `users` to get the currently logged in users."_ @dessert OP wants to know which users are active and not **idle**

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson OP does **not** speak of multiple users but rather explicitly just of *the user name* and *the active one*. `w` or `who` or `users` don't do the same as **whoami**, plus even if OP meant another thing (and needs to clarify the question then) other people actually searching for `whoami` will probably land here.

Comment: I clarified the question, so of course it is easy to get the currently active user, when the script I run runs under that user. But my script runs e.g. as a cron job in a different context, so I cannot just ask "Who am I?"…

Comment: @rugk Instead of downvoting my answer you should add that information to your question and furthermore clarify how a user *using the desktop* is defined exactly.

Comment: It's already there. First sentence/paragraph.