# How to find unlocked tty in linux?

Tags: linux, tty, getty

I just discovered that when I have an tty open in the background my lockscreen is useless. I sometimes use another tty to kill some process and then I forget the unlocked tty.  That is why I want to show a symbol in my polybar to show if I have unlocked sessions in the background.

I found out that there is a systemd unit running `getty@ttyX.service` for every tty I switched to at least once.  But I cannot find out if the session is still logged in or not.

Do you know a way to check if I have open tty sessions in the background?

Comment: You say "unlocked sessions in the background".  I believe `loginctl` can tell *if* the session supports it; `loginctl show-session SESSION_NUMBER -a` shows `LockedHint=no` (or `yes`).  However there are text console screen lockers and I suspect they don't support `loginctl`.  Please edit to clarify if there is a specific console locker that you are interested in supporting.  Or if you are simply happy to know whether the user is logged in on a text console or not.

Comment: @sourcejedi simply knowing it is enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `w` command list users with shells and the corresponding terminal, so

```
w | grep -e 'tty[0-9]'
```

returns rc=0 if there is an open TTY session, and 1 if not.

Comment: This will also count graphical sessions in certain environments.

Comment: To be specific, I use a Gnome Wayland session (the Fedora Workstation default), and it shows my Gnome session as `tty2`, so this answer will not work.  On other environments it may show `:0` (the display number, which relates to an X Windows based session).

Comment: @sourcejedi thanks for adding the explanation! On one of my systems there’s even a mixture, `:0` etc. for some X sessions and `tty2` etc. for other X sessions (I get the impression it might depend on whether `gnome-shell` has crashed and restarted yet or not).

Comment: @StephenKitt "yet" :-D.  Interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If `loginctl` knows about your sessions, you can use that (riffing off [How to return the currently active user/session on a graphical Linux desktop session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/394709/86440)):

```
for sessionid in $(loginctl list-sessions --no-legend | awk '{ print $1 }')
do loginctl show-session -p User -p Type -p Remote $sessionid | sort
done |
awk -F= '/Type/ { type = $2 } /Remote/ { remote = $2 } /User/ && remote == "no" && type == "tty" { sessions++ } END { print sessions }'
```

will count the number of non-remote tty sessions currently open.